# Returning back all the fields and not the fields selected

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I have a web page with list of 5 fields. I am trying to generate output depending on the fields selected by the user.

Here is the code I currently have in place that works fine.

```
fields = {field: value for field, value in form.data.items() if
              value != None  or value != 'csrf_token'}
print(fields)
## This prints out a list of all fields

o = []
for a in fields:
    if a is not None:
        o.append(a)
print(o)

p = o[:-1]
print(p)


output = sample_function(*p)
```

The problem I am having is irrespective of which fields are selected, the output is the same (it returns back all fields irrespective of whether they are selected or not).

Could anyone advise as to where am I going wrong with this. Thanks.

Update:

```
@app.route('/index', methods=['GET','POST'])
def sample_function():
form = SampleForm()
if form.validate_on_submit():
    store_id = form.store_id.data
    store_name = form.store_name.data
    location_id = form.location_id.data
    store_type = form.store_type.data
    store_location = form.store_location.data

fields = {field: value for field, value in form.data.items() if
              value != None  or value != 'csrf_token'}
print(fields)
## This prints out a list of all fields

o = []
for a in fields:
    if a is not None:
        o.append(a)
print(o)

p = o[:-1]
print(p)


output = sample_function(*p)
```

Function that runs the query:

```
def sample_function(*field_names):
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute('select {} from table.format(', '.join(str(field) for field in field_names)))
```

Comment: Hi there, `if value != None or key != 'None' or key != 'csrf_token'` the `or` here is redundant. Any key will pass the checks. Did you mean to use `and`?

Comment: @TrebuchetMS it was a typo I entered key != None twice.. I have edited the post

Comment: @TrebuchetMS the problem still exists though..

Comment: In that first comment, I've merely pointed out what I think was unintentional. Looking at your question, I'm still confused how your fields are selected by the user and how that ties in with the code you've shown. Please elaborate...?

Comment: @TrebuchetMS as mentioned in my initial post, I have a web page with 5 fields(check boxes). As a user I can select any of the fields. Based on the user input, an excel get generated with the fields selected.. If all the check boxes are selected, the excel gets generated. However if I uncheck one of the checkboxes, it still returns the same output with all columns.. I have updated my initial post the complete form with the SQL that gets executed on submission..

Comment: @TrebuchetMS Hope the updated post helps..

Comment: Again `if value != None  or value != 'csrf_token'` is redundant, since any `value` will pass the condition as True. I doubt this is your intention.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184151/discussion-between-dark-horse-and-trebuchetms).